# Texture strech not showing on UV edit map

Tags: texturing, uv

Im having an issue with an awful looking stretched texture while following blender gurus' Anvil tutorial, the two small holes at the back have a horrid stretched look around the rim but it does not show up in the UV edit map.

I assumed it was a result of the SubDiv modifier and tried marking the top edges as sharp but it made no difference, I am very much a beginner here so apologies if I am missing something obvious

[image: awful stretching]

[image: awful stretching2]

Comment: Did you try to re-unwrap the holes?

Comment: Yes I have tried a few times to re-seam and unwrap but these stretches appear everytime, confusing because both holes are seperate islands on the UV map

Comment: This looks like a kind of malfunction of the Subdivision Surface modifier. Try to increase the "Mean Crease" on the rims of the holes. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html?highlight=mean%20crease#weighted-edge-creases